# Selecting JSON key using Haskell

Tags: json, haskell

I am trying to select the top-most key from this JSON, which would be the text "title." How can I do this in Haskell?

{
    "title" : {
        "body" : 2
    }
}

Comment: I would recommend using the widely used [`aeson`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.0) package for JSON data, it's quite easy to use, and is pretty well documented with a lot of tutorial material out there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found to the problem using lens if anybody is looking for answer in the future:

$> :t exampleJSON 
exampleJSON :: Value

listToMaybe $ views (_Just . _Object) (\obj -> fmap fst (toList obj))  exampleJSON